# Symfony collection of specific type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a form type that allows me to select files from an ajax loaded file list.
I was thinking of extending the collection type with allow add and allow remove options, and then create a custom form rendering, but how do I do this extending so I set the collection options, and specify my own type options, but do not expose the collection options?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up by duplicating the relevant code of the collection type, and hardcoding/changing the logic where required. This gives some extra code(about 12 lines), but works like a charm.